# Two Configuration files in Scala-Spray framework

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I have REST API, that is developed using Scala and Spray framework. I am able to execute and launch my Api from localhost. The API is connected to the database. The IP Address(localhost) and port  of Database is read from the "application.conf" file under the resources.

Everything works fine till I start using Docker. In Docker I have :
1. One Docker container of Rest API
2. One Docker container of Database.

The IP address of Database changes for each docker instance, therefore I need to update my "application.conf" file. Although I can use the hostname of Db instance that remains the same.

My issue is : Can I have two "application.conf" files , one for localhost and one for Docker instance? IS there a way to change the "application.conf" file at the run time.

P.s I am using "sbt run" to run the application and as per documentation it does not support java system properties or environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can choose the config at runtime. spray & akka use the typesafe config library which allows setting single settings or the whole configuration using JVM properties.

From the [documentation of config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/#standard-behavior):

> For applications using `application.{conf,json,properties}`, system
>   properties can be used to force a different config source:
>
> - `config.resource` specifies a resource name - not a    basename, i.e. `application.conf` not `application`
> - `config.file` specifies a filesystem path, again    it should include the extension, not be a basename
> - `config.url` specifies a URL
>
> These system properties specify a *replacement* for
>   `application.{conf,json,properties}`, not an addition. They only
>   affect apps using the default `ConfigFactory.load()` configuration. In
>   the replacement config file, you can use `include "application"` to
>   include the original default config file; after the include statement
>   you could go on to override certain settings.